# Difficulties generating a matrix table with LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to query a Matrix Table with LINQ using these models:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLine
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
}
```

What I am trying to get out: **Get number of sold products per month.**

[image: How I want to display the data in HTML]

### My Query so far

```
var matrix = (from o in Context.Orders
                group o by o.DateCreated.Month
                into grp
                select new ReportingMatrix
                {
                    Month = grp.Key,
                    MatrixData = (from p in grp
                        from li in p.OrderLines
                        group li by li.ProductId
                        into lgr
                        select new ReportingMatrixData
                        {
                            ProductCode = (from pr in lgr
                                group pr by pr.Product.ProductName
                                into pgp
                                select pgp.Key).FirstOrDefault(),
                            Cases = lgr.Sum(l => l.Quantity)
                        }).ToList()
                }).ToList();
```

This works "somewhat" but there are issues I need to solve.

In March I had 10 products. 
In April I created 2 more. 
In August another 3 more.

So for Jan - March I want to see the products I created in April and August, with a sold number of 0. Right now these products are left out out of the Data collection.

This makes it difficult to loop over in my view. I want the collection of data to reflect all products and if they did not exist in February, then simply display 0.

The ViewModels I use to query into:

```
public class ReportingMatrix
{
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public List<ReportingMatrixData> MatrixData { get; set; }
}

public class ReportingMatrixData
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int Cases { get; set; }
}
```

### Questions

1. What changes do I need to make to my query to do what I want it to
   do?
2. How would I loop over the data to create the table in my HTML?
3. I am now using an int for the Month, but I'd really like to get the
   string representation. Not been able to make that work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the best approach is to try to put it in one Linq query only.

Just create separate queries for selecting distinct months and product, then create a linq query which sums the orders for the given product and month. Allowing 0 as default result value.

This will also more easily address 2. and 3.
Additional hint, to get all month names:

```
someDateTime.Month.ToString("MMMM")
```

or use the first code snippet from: 
http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/09/month-names-c-datetime-culture.html

Other suggestion: research other join types like *full join, outer join*